# menu fade in effect on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<ul style="#" class="hmenu">
    <li class="active selected"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have a menu with one link as `active`. I use this script to switch active class on hover

```
$('.hmenu li').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $('.hmenu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
$('.hmenu li').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('.hmenu li[class=selected]').addClass('active');
});
```

This work's but i want to change it so that when i hover any link, the link should fadeIn and fadeOut on mouseleave.

I can't get my head around this - How can i do this ?

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GdSUg/

Comment: what do you mean by `the link should fadeIn and fadeOut ` .. u mean to say the backround color should fadein and fadeout..  bit confused..

Comment: yes.. on mouseenter it the background-color should fadeIn and on mouseleave it should fadeOut

Answer (score 1):

Add the:

```
transition: all 1s;
```

to the css code in the class .active

[this is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/GdSUg/4/)

See the reference for more information: [Here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp&ei=3cubUZeFIsWv4ASGroGIAw&usg=AFQjCNE_VsKUo3SCv7Rvug4AQcDPMO9eEA&sig2=qAr60-kL-tt8vHmEFe3DkQ&bvm=bv.46751780,d.bGE)

Comment: You forgot to set `transition` on `.hmenu li` for the fade out effect

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Why do you ask when you already know the answer. `:P`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I wasn't just trying to make the point, I was trying to help Simone with what he should address in an answer. If you're doing CSS transition, you might as well drop all the JavaScript btw.

Comment: @XTop what browsers do you need to support?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yeah, I just meant you could've been more direct to the point as "This won't work in IE<=9", but I see your point. `transition` and `:hover` would be a better way around if using transitions as you mentioned.

Comment: @XTop then no, this will fail on IE<=9

Answer (score 1):

CSS transitions are one way. Another is to use jQuery UI's built in `switchClass` functionality. [Using your demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GdSUg/21/):

```
$('.hmenu li').hover(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).switchClass('','active', 200);
}, function () {
    $(this).switchClass('active', '', 200);
});
```

*Requires*

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

*Reference*: http://jqueryui.com/switchClass/

You may notice weird behavior when quickly hovering over elements that require a delayed transition (i.e. - fade, slide) -- Consider using [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html):

> What is **hoverIntent**? 
>   hoverIntent is a plug-in that attempts to
>   determine the user's intent... like a crystal ball, only with mouse
>   movement! It is similar to jQuery's hover method. However, instead of
>   calling the handlerIn function immediately, hoverIntent waits until
>   the user's mouse slows down enough before making the call. Why? To
>   delay or prevent the accidental firing of animations or ajax calls.
>   Simple timeouts work for small areas, but if your target area is large
>   it may execute regardless of intent. That's where hoverIntent comes
>   in...

Comment: your solution has weird behavior....try moving mouse on all links horizontally and  quickly

Comment: That is an inherent issue with hover/mouseenter/leave and timed fades. You can solve this problem, by writing/[using additional code](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) that deals with that issue. It's not *my* solution as much it is a jQuery solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

There you go

```
$('.hmenu li').hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: "#89B908"
    }, 300);
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: "#FFF"
    }, 1);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hStNX/)

Comment: But i need to add active class on hover and on the selected li.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/49ef9/ this one does the foreground color to. You can keep the addClass you had before

Comment: `:(`  yes, that answer was correct,, well i undeleted that answer..thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To animate colours reliably with JQuery, you need to use the JQuery Color Plugin (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color). You can then do something like the following:

```
var active = {
    backgroundColor: '#89B908',
    color: '#FFF'
},
inactive = {
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    color: '#000'
};

$('.hmenu li').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).animate(active, function () {
        $('.hmenu li').removeClass('active').css(inactive);
        $(this).addClass('active').css(active);
    }).find('a').animate({
        color: '#FFF'
    });
});
$('.hmenu li').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).animate(inactive, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('.hmenu li.selected').addClass('active').css(active);
    }).find('a').animate({
        color: '#000'
    });
});
```

You can find a working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GdSUg/28/